# Uploading image to Imgur return 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, imgur

I have the following `HTML` and `Javascript` code to upload image to Imgur using their API. But I got 400 Bad Request error from their server. Could someone explain me why this is happening?

```js
function openFile(){
 var file = document.getElementById('profilePicture').files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader()
 reader.onload = function(){
  var dataURL = reader.result;
  $.ajax({ 
      url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Client-ID my-client-id-here-i-typed-correctly'
      },
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          'image': dataURL
      },
      success: function(data){ 
       console.log(data.data.link) 
      }
  });
 };

 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Upload</title>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
   <label>Upload a profile picture</label>
   <input type="file" id="profilePicture" name="file" placeholder="Upload profile picture" onchange="openFile()">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Uploading call the method and `Imgur` returns `400 (Bad Request)`. I could not figure it out why. So why?